# What's the range of the wrangler?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

How much extra range does the Engineer's sentry gun have when using The Wrangler? I know that its range is increased, but not the extent...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I understand, there's no range limit, just like there's no range limit for normal weapons (e.g. pistol).

[Here's also a source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/437678-team-fortress-2/55544707).

Comment: There also seems to be no damage falloff for the gun or rockets from sentries, so this makes it a very effective weapon, even from extreme range.

Comment: The only downside being that you have to aim manually.

Comment: There is a lot of aim-assist though.

Comment: @Shadur - The other downside is you burn through ammo quicker, and can't replenish and shoot at the same time (Good if you've got a dual-engie setup and the other guy isn't a douche)

Comment: Non-douche engies seem to be hard to find. Mostly because only the engie whose sentry is doing the actual shooting gets the points.